# Socket Server - Sending messages from client to client

Tags: actionscript-3, sockets, air, client

I have a socket server set up using Adobe AIR, and I am trying to allow two clients to send messages between each other using the server (this is an Android based project so the server has to act as the middle man on a PC). For some reason, the messages I am sending are only being sent back to the same client it came from, rather than to the other one as well. I have already set up a system to identify where each message has come from, and how to deal with it on the other side.

The variable 'connectionNum' int basically represent whether the client is number 0 or 1, and the data being sent to and from the server has either 0, or 1 in front of it.

Ideally I would like a way to direct data to one specific client at a time, rather than attempting to send it to both with the int at the start of every message.

At the moment, only the second client to connect's messages are actually sent through the server, the first sends a blank message, not sure why.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> At the moment, only the second client to connect's messages are actually sent through the server, the first sends a blank message, not sure why.

It is because you only have one `clientSocket` object on the server and you are overwriting it when someone else connects, so when the second client connects you are losing the first clients socket. When you call `sendData` on the server it is always using `clientSocket` which is whoever connected last.

To fix this you need an array of `clientSocket` objects on the server. Then you can pick the correct one to send a message to or send the message to all clients if you want to broadcast a message.